# How to list default constraint's columns in SQL Server using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, default-constraint

I am using the following query to list the table constraint(Primary Keys, Unique Keys, Foreign keys), however, I am having hard time in getting a list of foreign keys and its references (columns).

Can anyone please advise and show me how I can modified this code so that I could get a list of default constraint's columns while keeping PK, FK, UQ Key the same.

**I will need to use the code for my project, so I would appreciate if you could should me the complete code as I'm not familiar with SQL...

Here's my original code

```
"select table_view,
    object_type, 
    constraint_type,
    constraint_name,
    details,
    fk_columns,
    referenceTable,
    pk_columns
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details],
        '' fk_columns,
        '' pk_columns,
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    SELECT schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(objects.schema_id) + '.' + objects.[name] + '.' + col.[name] as details,
        col.[name] as [fk_columns],
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name,
        col2.[name] as [pk_columns]
    FROM
        sys.objects objects
        INNER JOIN sys.tables fk_tab on objects.object_id = fk_tab.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables pk_tab on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk_c on fk_c.parent_object_id = fk.parent_object_id
                       and fk_c.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            inner join sys.columns col
                            on fk_c.parent_object_id = col.object_id
                            and fk_c.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        left join sys.columns col2
                            on fk_c.referenced_object_id = col2.object_id
                            and fk_c.referenced_column_id = col2.column_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition],
         '' as [fk_columns],
        '' as [pk_columns],
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition],
         '' as [fk_columns],
        '' as [pk_columns],
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) a
where table_view like 'dbo%'
order by table_view, constraint_type, constraint_name"
```

And here's what I tried, but it's not working

> SQLServerException: All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

```
"select table_view,
    object_type, 
    constraint_type,
    constraint_name,
    details,
    fk_columns,
    referenceTable,
    pk_columns,
    df_columns
from (
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name] as table_view, 
        case when t.[type] = 'U' then 'Table'
            when t.[type] = 'V' then 'View'
            end as [object_type],
        case when c.[type] = 'PK' then 'Primary key'
            when c.[type] = 'UQ' then 'Unique constraint'
            when i.[type] = 1 then 'Unique clustered index'
            when i.type = 2 then 'Unique index'
            end as constraint_type, 
        isnull(c.[name], i.[name]) as constraint_name,
        substring(column_names, 1, len(column_names)-1) as [details],
        '' fk_columns,
        '' pk_columns,
        '' df_columns,
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.objects t
        left outer join sys.indexes i
            on t.object_id = i.object_id
        left outer join sys.key_constraints c
            on i.object_id = c.parent_object_id 
            and i.index_id = c.unique_index_id
       cross apply (select col.[name] + ', '
                        from sys.index_columns ic
                            inner join sys.columns col
                                on ic.object_id = col.object_id
                                and ic.column_id = col.column_id
                        where ic.object_id = t.object_id
                            and ic.index_id = i.index_id
                                order by col.column_id
                                for xml path ('') ) D (column_names)
    where is_unique = 1
    and t.is_ms_shipped <> 1
    union all 
    SELECT schema_name(fk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + fk_tab.name as foreign_table,
        'Table',
        'Foreign key',
        fk.name as fk_constraint_name,
        schema_name(objects.schema_id) + '.' + objects.[name] + '.' + col.[name] as details,
        col.[name] as [fk_columns],
        schema_name(pk_tab.schema_id) + '.' + pk_tab.name,
        col2.[name] as [pk_columns]
    FROM
        sys.objects objects
        INNER JOIN sys.tables fk_tab on objects.object_id = fk_tab.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk on fk_tab.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.tables pk_tab on pk_tab.object_id = fk.referenced_object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk_c on fk_c.parent_object_id = fk.parent_object_id
                       and fk_c.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            inner join sys.columns col
                            on fk_c.parent_object_id = col.object_id
                            and fk_c.parent_column_id = col.column_id
        left join sys.columns col2
                            on fk_c.referenced_object_id = col2.object_id
                            and fk_c.referenced_column_id = col2.column_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Check constraint',
        con.[name] as constraint_name,
        con.[definition],
         '' as [fk_columns],
        '' as [pk_columns],
        '' as [df_columns],
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.check_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id
    union all
    select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
        'Table',
        'Default constraint',
        con.[name],
        col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition],
         '' as [fk_columns],
        '' as [pk_columns],
        col.[name] as [df_columns],
        '' referenceTable
    from sys.default_constraints con
        left outer join sys.objects t
            on con.parent_object_id = t.object_id
        left outer join sys.all_columns col
            on con.parent_column_id = col.column_id
            and con.parent_object_id = col.object_id) a
where table_view like 'dbo%'
order by table_view, constraint_type, constraint_name"
```

Comment: Why not use the `information_schema` tables?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I heard about it but I'm not sure how I could find the default constraints' column name from it... I just started SQL recently and could only read basic sql query, someone help me with the code above... Would appreciate if you could show me what and where I could add/modify to get default constraints' column names.. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

After reviewing the code I do realize that I can get the columns' name by modifying constraint_name.

After Default constraint, change from con.[name] to col.[name]

```
select schema_name(t.schema_id) + '.' + t.[name],
    'Table',
    'Default constraint',
    col.[name],
    col.[name] + ' = ' + con.[definition],
     '' as [fk_columns],
    '' as [pk_columns],
    '' referenceTable
```